# Can a semiring other than monosemiring posses a common neutral element with respect to both the operations defined on it?

Tags: ring-theory, semiring

In general, a semiring contains two distinct identities with respect to addition and multiplication defined on it. In particular, monosemiring is the one in which the neutral element is common with respect to both the operations defined on it. I found some semiring like structures other than monosemiring  in which both the operations have same neutral element.

Comment: Part of the definition is that the additive identity is a multiplicative annihilator, so the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @Hayden you have rightly pointed out but i have been wondering that what is the significance\necessity  of additive identity being a multplicative annihilator. If we could show the non necessity of additive identity being a multiplicative annihilator would be an interesting result.